# Stop / Pause .runActionForever() SCNAction

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit

How do I pause or stop a SCNAction that was called by `.runActionForever()` without a key? I saw the option to use `node.removeActionForKey("action")` but my SCNAction does not have a key. This is how I create it:

```
var turnAction = SCNAction.rotateByX(0, y: 1, z: 0, duration: 1)
```

...and how it is used:

```
node.runAction(SCNAction.repeatActionForever(turnAction))
```

**What I tried**

I know there is the method `node.removeActionForKey("action")` but when I create a keyValue for my SCNAction it gets **void** and can no longer be used with `.repeatActionForever()`.

How can I stop it?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In SpriteKit (not sure of SceneKit) you have the runAction(act, withKey: key) this will create the key and you can later remove that action with its key.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I used it like this: `node.runAction(SCNAction.repeatActionForever(action), forKey: "action")` and then to stop it: `node.removeActionForKey("action")`. If you post your idea as an answer I'll be happy to accept it. You can implement my code in there ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To add an action with a key you use the

```
SCNNode.runAction(SCNAction, forKey: String)
```

method.

Now you can remove a specific action by that key

```
SCNNode.removeAction(forKey: String)
```

Comment: It is a SCNAction though... - SceneKit

Comment: `SCNNode` still has `runActionForKey` and `removeActionForKey` just like `SKNode`, though. See the docs for the [`SCNActionable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnactionable) protocol.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to end and remove all actions from the node, just use the following code:

```
node.removeAllActions()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just give the node another action and the previous one just stop. You can just say to your node to rotate by 0 (so nothing happen). Do something like:

```
nodeName.runAction(SCNAction.rotateByX(0,y:0,z:0), duration: 1)
```

Comment: This would would work when using CAAnimation, But SKActions are different.